# References on projectors

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, idempotents

What are good books or articles about linear projectors in Hilbert spaces?
I am mostly interested in the finite dimensional case (but anything is welcome).

All about idempotents, orthogonal and oblique projectors, partitions of identity, useful formulas, results, theorems...

Thanks!

(Feel free to modify tags appropriately.)

Comment: This is a somewhat interesting book I had a look in recently: http://www.amazon.com/Projectors-Projection-Methods-Advances-Mathematics/dp/1461348250

Answer (score 1):

For finite-dimensional oblique projectors I'd recommend the Springer monograph Ben-Israel and Greville *Generalized Inverses* doi 10.1007/b97366